# gettimeofday to calculate elapsed when day changes

Tags: c, time

The typical example that I see when trying to do measure elapsed time goes something like this:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main() {
 
  struct timeval start, end;
  gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
 
  //Do some operation
  gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

  unsigned long long end_time = (end.tv_sec * 1000000 + end.tv_usec);
  unsigned long long start_time = (start.tv_sec * 1000000 + start.tv_usec);

  printf("Time taken : %ld micro seconds\n", end_time - start_time);

  return 0;
}
```

This is great when it's somewhere mid day, but if someone were to run some tests late at night this wouldn't work. My approach is something like this to address it:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main() {
 
  struct timeval start, end;
  gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
 
  //Do some operation

  gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

  unsigned long long end_time = (end.tv_sec * 1000000 + end.tv_usec);
  unsigned long long start_time = (start.tv_sec * 1000000 + start.tv_usec);
  unsigned long long elapsed_time = 0;

  if ( end_time < start_time )
     //Made up some constant that defines 86,400,000,000 microseconds in a day
     elapsed_time = end_time + (NUM_OF_USEC_IN_A_DAY - start_time); 
  else
     elapsed_time = end_time - start_time;

  printf("Time taken : %ld micro seconds\n", elapsed_time);

  return 0;
}
```

Is there a better way of anticipating day change using `gettimeofday`?

Comment: "but if someone were to run some tests late at night this wouldn't work". It will work. [man gettimeofday](https://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday): `gives the number of seconds and microseconds since the Epoch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the name, `gettimeofday` results do not roll over daily. The `gettimeofday` seconds count, just like the `time` seconds count, started at zero on the first day of 1970 (specifically 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +00:00) and has been incrementing steadily ever since.  On a system with 32-bit `time_t`, it will roll over sometime in 2038; people are working right now to phase out the use of 32-bit `time_t` for this exact reason and we expect to be done well before 2038.

`gettimeofday` results are also independent of time zone and not affected by daylight savings shifts. They *can* go backward when the computer's clock is reset. If you don't want to worry about that, you can use `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC)` jnstead.

Comment: definitely got confused with the naming and the description in the man page. So is clock_gettime the solution to the 2038 problem?

Comment: No, clock_gettime also returns (a struct containing) a time_t. The solution to the 2038 problem is to change the size of time_t and recompile everything. Fortunately this only needs to happen on ILP32 ABIs.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to handle the case where `end.tv_sec` is less than `start.tv_sec`? Are you trying to account for `ntpd` changes? If so, and especially if you want to record only elapsed time, then use `clock_gettime` instead of `gettimeofday` as the former is immune to wall clock changes.

Answer (score 0):

> but if someone were to run some tests late at night this wouldn't work

That's an incorrect statement because `gettimeofday` is not relative to the start of each day but rather relative to a fixed point in time. From the [gettimeofday](https://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday) manual:

> gives the number of seconds and microseconds since the Epoch

So the first example will work as long as there are no jumps in time (e.g. due to manual time setting or NTP). Again from the manual:

> The time returned by gettimeofday() is affected by discontinuous
> jumps in the system time (e.g., if the system administrator manually
> changes the system time).  If you need a monotonically increasing
> clock, see clock_gettime(2).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way of anticipating day change using gettimeofday?

In addition to other problems identified in various answers, the following is also subject integer overflow when `time_t` is only 32-bit.  Instead scale by a `(unsigned) long long` constant.

```
// unsigned long long end_time = (end.tv_sec * 1000000 + end.tv_usec);
long long end_time = (end.tv_sec * 1000000ll + end.tv_usec);

// Use correct specifier, not %ld for unsigned long long
// printf("Time taken : %ld micro seconds\n", elapsed_time);
long long elapsed_time = end_time - start_time;
printf("Time taken : %lld micro seconds\n", elapsed_time);
```

---

Tip: enables all compiler warnings.